# How to search using key typed in Swing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

How to search for data in sort alphabetically using key typed?
When the first letter on the keyboard do not appear in alphabetical order, but two letters and so on type will sequentially in alphabetical order.

I have Method :

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            try {
                table.setModel(tableModel);
                SearCh();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

private void SearCh() throws ErrorInfo, SQLException {
    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    DaoBarang dao = MappingDbBarang.getDaoBarang();
    tableModel.setList(dao.cariBarang(textField.getText()));
}
```

I ask, how to keep the data in the table appear in alphabetical order when I type a letter?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: JTable searching and filtering capabilities...

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for working examples.